# How do I connect a button to a Dialog that will edit a TextView, within a FrameLayout, with a users input?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-dialogfragment

I don't understand DialogFragment at all. How to create one, how to get the user input out of it, and set it into a TextView.

I would like for the TITLE button, when clicked, to bring up a DialogFragment asking the user to enter the title of their Mood Board.  The user enters a title. When they click the PostiveButton "Done", the user's title is set into the top left frame of the mood board, which has a TextView with a hint.

Please! Ask questions, because I don't really understand the dialog setup.

Here is a picture of my main_layout, in my MainActivity. Every element has an "@+id/".

[image]

Comment: Adding a custom layout to an alert dialog is kins of hard, is easier to use dialog. The simpler way to do so would be to have a field on the activity creating the dialog in the activity and the clicklistener for ok button would dismiss the dialog and will get the dialog text and ser it to the activity

Comment: You can make your mood board title textview static then call it to the alertdialog with edittext to set it text (setText).

Comment: @cutiko Do you mean a <fragement> in the XML? My professor wants us to press a button, dialog box pops up, then edit some text, then I was hoping to have that text be delivered to the Top Left Frame Layout inside of the Mood Board, which is a Constraint layout with several Frame Layouts withing it. Is this possible? I don't mind doing it differently I just don't want to deviate from what is asked of me to much.

Comment: Take a look at this gist https://gist.github.com/cutiko/348d5dee496d7abfd022d8a2e81ec812 I dont know why you nentioned the fragment tag

Comment: @Cutiko I'm sorry. I need start from the beginning because I don't understand the where all the github code is supposed to go, what parts I am supposed to use. I don't know why, but I cannot seem to understand this.

Comment: @L2_Paver Hi, I tried to understand the example you gave me, but I am still lost. I need example code and if for it to be broken down into laymen terms. I think dialog stuff is harder than it needs to be. idk. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you are looking for is a callback:

1. Create an interface with a method to use as a callback
2. Implements the interface on the activity
3. Create the dialog fragment and in onAttach get the interface
4. Show the dialog fragment on the activity
5. On dismiss the dialog fragment pass the text using the instance of the interface

```
interface Callback {
    updateText(String text)
}
```

```
class CoolActivity... implements Callback

onCreate {
    //find your views
    showDialogBtn.setOnClickListener(...
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("yourTag");
        if (prev != null) {
            ft.remove(prev);
        }
        ft.addToBackStack(null);

        DialogFragment dialogFragment = ExampleDialogFragment.newInstance();
        dialogFragment.show(ft, "yourTag");
     )
}


@Override
updateText(String text) {
    youtView.setText(text)
}
```

```
class CoolDialogFragment extend DialogFragment {

     private Callback callback;


     @Override
      void onAttach(Context context) {
          callback = (Callback) context
      }

      @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_example, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
         //find the views in the dialog fragment
         closeBtn.clickListener(...
               callback.updateText(edittext.getText().toString())
               dismiss()
         )
    }
}
```

Here is a gist of a dialog fragment
https://gist.github.com/cutiko/7e307efcf7492ea52ef05cd90f9e3203

The problem is you want to connect a dialog fragment with a another component, and you want to do it straigth forward. This is not considered a good practice because yiu create 2 componentes higly attached, so the best would be to use data persistence and some form of react programming

Comment: What class should the interface                                                               interface Callback {
    updateText(String text) 
} be in.

Comment: An interface can be a class by its own, an Interface is defined as a special kind of class, if you want ir nested then it should be the activity because is the activity callback

Comment: I don't have a layout made for a dialog fragment. So I cant get views from it because it doesn't exist

Comment: I don't care what my professor wants anymore. I have hated these dialogs' since the beginning of class. They are to hard to work with. I just want that title button to help the user change the title of the mood board.

Comment: Create a dialog then and the problem is not dialog is the design pattern used, I would never do that on a real app.

Comment: I'm sorry. My professor isn't much help and I would like to do things the right way and the best way of practice.

Comment: I would create a layout for the dialog fragment, deliver the assigment, understand my professor is doing soemthing wrong and then learn Android Jetpack, which you wont be able to learn in an assigment span of time

Answer (score 0):

You can make your mood board title textview static then call it to the alertdialog with edittext to set it text (setText)
like this.

```
   final EditText edittext = new EditText(MainActivity.this);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage("Input Title")
                .setView(edittext)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        YourCustomDialog.your_title_textviewMoodboard.setText(edittext.getText().toString());

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

in  your custom dialog. declare your textview static globally

```
public static TextView your_title_textviewMoodboard;
```

Comment: I think I need some sleep. I can look this in the morning. I think I am starting to see shapes. Thank you. :)